# Emmeans and 95% confidence intervals for linear mixed models (two center study)

Tags: mixed-model, confidence-interval, multiple-comparisons, lsmeans

I am having problems estimating **emmeans and 95% CI per group with linear mixed models.**
I have put my questions at the end of my post.

In short, I want to compare a continuous outcome between 7 groups of patients (total 250 individuals). I have data from two hospitals, which include a total of 4 studies:

**Center 1:**

- Study 1

**Center 2:**

- Study 2
- Study 3
- Study 4

Each study measured the outcome with different equipment, so i might want to correct for that. There are also several binary and continuous independent variables i definitely want to correct for.

**So i have these variables:**

- Outcome (continuous)
- Hospital (Factor, with 2 levels)
- Study(Factor, with 4 levels)
- several binary and continuous independent variables

**I used the following models:**

**MODEL 1: Random effects: only hospital**

```
m1 <- lmer(outcome ~ groups.factor + continuous_IV_1 + continuous_IV_2 + binary_IV_1 + binary_IV_2
 + binary_IV_3 + binary_IV_4 + (1 | hospital), data= data, REML= TRUE)

emmeans(m1, pairwise ~ "groups.factor", adjust="None")

Groups                emmean  SE    df lower.CL upper.CL

Group 1                2.28 0.335 3.24    1.257     3.30

Group 2                2.58 0.295 1.95    1.282     3.88

Group 3                2.56 0.275 1.48    0.870     4.24

Group 4                2.11 0.273 1.43    0.349     3.87

Group 5                1.74 0.277 1.53    0.112     3.36

Group 6              1.32 0.273 1.42   -0.450     3.09

Group 7              2.22 0.319 2.65    1.130     3.32



Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

- In this example the confidence intervals are very wide. It even estimated EM means as negative, while this is impossible and all my outcome measures are positive (see group 6).

**MODEL 2:Random effects: only study**

```
m2 <- lmer(outcome ~ groups.factor + continuous_IV_1 + continuous_IV_2 + binary_IV_1 + binary_IV_2
 + binary_IV_3 + binary_IV_4 + (1 | study), data= data, REML= TRUE)

emmeans(m2, pairwise ~ "groups.factor", adjust="None")

Groups                emmean  SE    df lower.CL upper.CL
Group 1               2.43 0.288 13.45    1.811     3.05
Group 2                2.58 0.247  7.30    1.998     3.16
Group 3                2.56 0.228  5.22    1.983     3.14
Group 4                2.10 0.223  4.80    1.525     2.68
Group 5                1.80 0.232  5.58    1.225     2.38
Group 6               1.37 0.227  5.11    0.787     1.94
Group 7              2.25 0.277 11.23    1.639     2.85

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

**MODEL 3:Random effects: study nested in hospital**

```
m3 <- lmer(outcome ~ groups.factor + continuous_IV_1 + continuous_IV_2 + binary_IV_1 + binary_IV_2
 + binary_IV_3 + binary_IV_4 + (1 | hospital/study), data= data, REML= TRUE)

emmeans(m3, pairwise ~ "groups.factor", adjust="None")

Groups                emmean  SE    df lower.CL upper.CL
Group 1                2.43 0.402 1.60   0.2058     4.66
Group 2                2.58 0.370 0.88  -3.8853     9.04
Group 3                2.56 0.352 0.65 -14.2372    19.36
Group 4                2.10 0.355 0.58 -26.9052    31.11
Group 5                1.80 0.350 0.72  -9.7890    13.39
Group 6               1.37 0.345 0.67 -13.8482    16.58
Group 7               2.25 0.377 1.50  -0.0148     4.515

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

- In this example the confidence intervals are extremely wide and also very negative (while none of my outcome measurents are below 0).

**MODEL 4:Normal linear regression with correction for hospital**

```
m4 <- lm(outcome ~ groups.factor + continuous_IV_1 + continuous_IV_2 + binary_IV_1 + binary_IV_2
 + binary_IV_3 + binary_IV_4 + hospital, data= data)

emmeans(m4, pairwise ~ "groups.factor", adjust="None")

Groups                 emmean    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 Group 1                2.28 0.228 265     1.83     2.72
 Group 2                2.58 0.164 265     2.25     2.90
 Group 3                2.56 0.125 265     2.31     2.80
 Group 4                2.10 0.120 265     1.87     2.34
 Group 5                1.74 0.130 265     1.49     2.00
 Group 6             1.33 0.119 265     1.09     1.56
 Group 7               2.23 0.203 265     1.83     2.63
```

**Based on these results I have several questions:**

- Why are the emmeans confidence intervals so large when using linear mixed models? I would expect these confidence intervals to be smaller when correcting for study and/or hospital. The confidence intervals are the smallest in the normal linear regression model (model 4).
- How can the lower bound of the 95%CI for some groups be negative, while the outcome for every patient is positive.
- Can I use a binary variable (hospital) as a random effect? I have read that you need at least 5 levels. What is the best way to correct for two hospitals?
- How is the EM mean confidence interval calculated in linear mixed models? For the linear regression model the 95% interval can be calculated with SE*1.96, but this is clearly not the case for linear mixed models.

I hope you guys can help me! :)

Comment: The SEs are smallest in the last model because hospital is treated as a fixed effect - hence we don't include the variance of hospital effects in those SEs. However, those estimates apply only to those hospitals and should not be generalized to other hospitals. The models where hospital is random do generalize to other hospitals. If you were to look at *contrasts or comparisons* of group means, much of the the hospital effects will cancel out, and it could be that the fixed model does not have the lowest SEs for those.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I still have some questions:How would you recommend to analyse my data?  Can i use study as random effect, as it only has 4 levels? Can i nest studies in hospital (model 3)? Why are the confidence intervals of the emmeans so large in model 2 and 3? I used the Kenward-Roger method. Should I use another method?

Comment: I think your best bet is to use model #4 except replace hospital with factor(study) so that you account for the variation among studies (which includes the variation among hospitals, assuming they are numbered 1,2,3,4 as described. Your inferences apply only to those 4 particular studies, and 2 hospitals, but trying to expand inferences beyond those by including study as a random effect (model 2) is like having a sample size of 4 for the between-study effects.

Comment: That said, if the main focus is on comparing/contrasting within-study effects, there is likely not much difference in those contrasts between model 2 and (my revised version of) model 4.